# Why an angular 8 app is idling for a long time

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools, angular8

I am trying to understand how I could improve the loading time of my webpage. I have quickly noticed long idle times (about 40%) but I am struggling to understand what the issue could be. Here is a sample of the performances.

[image]

**API call**

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.blogService.getBlogs()
                    .subscribe(data => {
                      this.blogs = data;
                    },error => console.log(error));
  }
```

**Service**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.blogService.getBlogs()
                    .subscribe(data => {
                        this.blogs = data;
                    },error => console.log(error));
}
```

**Parent element html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let blog of blogs">
                    <app-blog-preview [id]="blog.id" [title]="blog.title" [banner]="blog.banner" [description]="blog.description" [postDate]="blog.postDate"></app-blog-preview>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Child element html (app-blog-preview)**

```
<div>
    <a [routerLink]="['/blog', id]"><h1 >{{title}}</h1></a>
    <p> 
      <img [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,' + banner" alt="" id="pic">
        {{description}}
    </p>
</div>
```

I would like to understand what is the issue or what should I do in order to understand where the problem is coming from. Many thanks.

Comment: It probably waits to this.blogService.getBlogs() finish.

Comment: Get blogs response data could be very high. Check network response time of the url hit in browser developer tool inspector  tool using  Ctrl shift I command in your browser.

Comment: The call is the grey bar between 465 ms and 565 ms (it overlaps a little) on the first picture. When I take a look at the network tab I can see a similar result for this call which is about 100 ms.